# All the possible locations of a NullPointerException? (SpigotMC)

Tags: nullpointerexception, null, minecraft, bukkit

So I had a function called setOwner as shown...

```
public void setOwner(Player player){

    this.setGoalTarget((EntityLiving)((CraftPlayer)player).getHandle(), EntityTargetEvent.TargetReason.CUSTOM, false);
}
```

And I used this function in:

```
pet.setOwner(e.getEntity().getKiller());
        pet.setName("&a" + e.getEntity().getKiller().getName() + "'s pet");
```

So when this code is ran, it gives a `NullPointerException` that looks like this:

```
[21:14:43] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not pass event EntityDeathEvent to Necro v1.0
org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:319) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:589) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:576) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.event.CraftEventFactory.callEntityDeathEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:762) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityLiving.d(EntityLiving.java:1447) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityLiving.die(EntityLiving.java:1395) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityLiving.damageEntity(EntityLiving.java:1241) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityEnderDragon.dealDamage(EntityEnderDragon.java:530) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityEnderDragon.a(EntityEnderDragon.java:500) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityComplexPart.damageEntity(SourceFile:47) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityHuman.attack(EntityHuman.java:1068) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityPlayer.attack(EntityPlayer.java:1632) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:2001) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PacketPlayInUseEntity.a(SourceFile:74) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PacketPlayInUseEntity.a(SourceFile:13) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:19) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(SourceFile:144) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(SourceFile:118) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.bb(MinecraftServer.java:942) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:935) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(SourceFile:127) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:919) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:851) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityEnderDragon cannot be cast to class net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityCreature (net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityEnderDragon and net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityCreature are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.entity.CraftCreature.getHandle(CraftCreature.java:14) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.entity.CraftCreature.getHandle(CraftCreature.java:1) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    at com.TheRealBee.e.listener.PetEvent.onEntityDeath(PetEvent.java:18) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:315) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
    ... 27 more
```

... why? Where are all the possible `NullPointerException`? I checked through the warnings and found nothing there so I already did that, don't tell me "Oh ViciousBee did you check the warnings..."

Edit: The correct error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R3.entity.CraftPlayer.getHandle()" because "player" is null
at com.TheRealBee.e.CustomCreature.setOwner(CustomCreature.java:27) ~[?:?]
at com.TheRealBee.e.listener.PetEvent.onEntityDeath(PetEvent.java:21) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:315) ~[Server.jar:2991-Spigot-018b9a0-f3f3094]
... 34 more
```

Comment: There is no NullPointerException anywhere in the error you posted. The actual relevant lines are `java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityEnderDragon cannot be cast to class net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityCreature` and `at com.TheRealBee.e.listener.PetEvent.onEntityDeath(PetEvent.java:18)`.

Comment: Uhh I think I posted the wrong error (Maybe? I'm not too sure) so I think I'll edit it :) (Sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that looking and reading stack traces could be a little difficult to recognize what the actual error is or where it occurred in your code.

Looking at the stack trace, you would see two exceptions:

1. **`org.bukkit.event.EventException`**.  This first one just tells you that the exception occurred in an event or listener. There are other types too, like a command exception: `org.bukkit.command.CommandException`.
2. **`java.lang.ClassCastException`**.  This is the main one you should focus on.
   According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html), this exception tells you that the code has tried to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance.

A `ClassCastException` will occur if you are casting, let's say an Integer, to a String, like this:

```java
Object x = new Integer(0);
System.out.println((String)x);
```

The exception will be thrown because String is not an instance of Integer.

In your code, the `ClassCastException` occurred in line 18 of the `PetEvent` class, as seen in your stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityEnderDragon cannot be cast to class net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityCreature (net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityEnderDragon and net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R3.EntityCreature are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    ...
    at com.TheRealBee.e.listener.PetEvent.onEntityDeath(PetEvent.java:18) ~[?:?]
```

It also tells you that you are casting `EntityEnderDragon` to `EntityCreature`.

Comment: sorry for the *1 year late* response but thanks